# Combing async function and sql query

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to async functions and I'm struggling getting it do work with db queries...
Here's what I have:

```
fetch: async (id) => {
  if (id!=='something') {
    return await db.getConnection().query("SELECT user FROM `table` WHERE id='" + id + "'", function (err, result) {
      if (err) { throw err }
      else {
        console.log(result[0].user);
        return result[0].user;
      }
    });
  }
  throw new Error('Failed fetching installation');
}
```

This results in getting an error: `Cannot read property 'user' of undefined` , but **after** this error, the console.log comes in indicating `result[0]` is actually defined.

So my guess is that it's not waiting for the result or something like that (even though it's not hitting the `throw new Error`).
Anyway, I'm sure this is just me not getting this right... as said, I'm only just getting started with these kinds of async behaviors.

Comment: You're mixing promises and callbacks. Also note that `return result[0].user;` is *not* returning from your custom fetch function; it returns inside the callback function and the value ends up nowhere. If `query()` returns a promise, then you need to use `query(...).then(result => { ... })` instead of passing the result handler as callback. Also note that this is the most basic usage of whatever db module you're using so the docs should tell you how to do this.

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for your reply! Are you sure I can use `.then` on `Connection.query()`? I'm using NodeJS btw, I forgot that tag initially.

Comment: ts tells me: `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Query'`

Comment: You'll probably want to use this then? https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper (I'm guessing at the module since you still haven't told us)

Comment: Awesome, that was it! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you are mixing promises and callbacks. I am unsure if my example below is possible with your database library, but I think if it is, its a much cleaner approach.

```
const fetch = async (id) => {
  if (id !== 'something') {
    try {
      const query = await db
        .getConnection()
        .query("SELECT user FROM `table` WHERE id='" + id + "'")
      return query[0].user
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      throw new Error(`Execution of query failed with error: ${error}`)
    }
  }
  throw new Error('Failed fetching installation')
}
const user = fetch('your-id') // (prefix fetch with await if not at top level)
```